# Extra expense to complete tasks. Do I pay or does the company pay?

Tags: expenses

I work as a remote teacher with a business in Asia. Employees set up the time and coordinate the classroom on their own and work on personal laptops. Occasionally there are technical problems such as low internet connections. Our boss says that we are getting paid and we can invest our salary back into a good network line or wifi.

I don't think employees should be expected to use their salaries to complete the job. Isn't it the responsibility of the company to ensure its employees (and essentially its business) the best work environment?

Similarly, I work full-time and if I find that I need external resources to help me, or I need to take a hundred-buck Udemy course that is relevant to my project, or I need to use paid software such as IntelliJ, do I use my own money or should I ask my supervisor for funds? For courses and extra help, will that make me look like I'm low-qualified. They can say everyone can complete tasks without courses, or there are free courses.

If they agree, what will it be like, do they add the extra to my salary?

Comment: Unless specified by law, this is entirely up to the relationship between you and your employer. If you want them to pay for these kind of things, negotiate it into your contract. And to forestall your response: there is no "standard".

Comment: Why would you need to pay for IntelliJ? There is a free educational/community edition. Anyway, are you an employee? or a contractor? What does your contract say? In which jurisdiction is this in? Asia is not specific enough.

Comment: If you are an employee, the employer pays. If you are a contractor, making a lot more money per day, and the expense is tax deductible, then you pay. The rule is that 120 to 150 daily rates would be your annual salary before any taxes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Extra expense to complete tasks. Do I pay or does the company pay?

This depends on the company.

I currently work for a company where they provide all materials/services at no cost to me.

I have worked for companies where I have had to purchase materials/services and was reimbursed by the company.

Finally, I have worked for a company that would not provide or reimburse employees for some materials/services.

You seem to currently be working for the third example, in which case there is little recourse other than asking them for what you need.  After that it is up to them what they want to do, and up to you to either accept or reject their proposal.  If you do accept, make sure that it is in writing.

Other than that, your best option would be to look for a company that provides the materials/services that their employees need to perform their work or at least will reimburse you if you need to make the purchase yourself.  Once again, make sure that these details are in writing before accepting an offer.